# StaleElementReferenceException in selenium

Tags: python, selenium, exception, nosetests

I am facing stale element error in selenium. After searching on google, it seems that one has to retry the click event to avoid this error. I am using selenium with python nosetests and many of the testcases have already been written, I wanted to know if there is some way where in without editing the testcases I can handle this error.

Comment: Can you please post your code and error message so that people can help  you out with your problem?

Answer (score 0):

The reasons that cause this exception to occur are described [here](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.jsp). It generally means that an element that previously was detected became unavailable for some reason.

In any case, there are thing you can try but all these will require code change. Be it modifying wait times or anything more complicated.